# Move files according to searchPattern

Tags: c#, filesystems

I have excel list with file names that I want to move from one folder to another. And I can not just copy paste the files from one folder to another since there are allot of files that do not match the excel list.

```
  private static void CopyPaste()
    {
        var pstFileFolder = "C:/Users/chnikos/Desktop/Test/";
        //var searchPattern = "HelloWorld.docx"+"Test.docx";
        string[] test = { "HelloWorld.docx", "Test.docx" };
        var soruceFolder = "C:/Users/chnikos/Desktop/CopyTest/";

        // Searches the directory for *.pst
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(pstFileFolder, test.ToString()))
        {
            // Exposes file information like Name
            var theFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            var destination = soruceFolder + theFileInfo.Name;
                File.Move(file, destination);

        }
    }
}
```

I have tried several things but I still think that with a array it would be the easiest way to do it(correct me if I am wrong).

The issue that I face right now is that it can not find any files (there are files under this name.

Comment: So you are looking for files that have the extension `.docx`? The searchPattern is incorrect, cause this will be `System.String[]`

Comment: @Jehof kind of but I have to differentiate them with the name since that is my  unique "key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the files in the directory by using [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) and use a linq expression to check if the file is contained in you string array.

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(pstFileFolder).Where (d => test.Contains(Path.GetFileName(d)));
```

So your foreach would look like
this

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(pstFileFolder).Where (d => test.Contains(Path.GetFileName(d)))
{
    // Exposes file information like Name
    var theFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
    var destination = soruceFolder + theFileInfo.Name;
    File.Move(file, destination);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually no, this will not search the directory for pst files. Either build the path yourself using Path.Combine and then iterate over the string-array, or use your approach. With the code above, you need to update the filter, because it will not find any file when given a string[].ToString (). This should do:

```
Directory.GetFiles (pstFileFolder, "*.pst")
```

Alternatively, you can iterate over all files without a filter and compare the filenames to your string-array. For this, a `List<string>` would be a better way. Just iterate over the files like you're doing and then check if the List contains the file via `List.Contains`.

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles (pstFileFolder))
{
    // Exposes file information like Name
    var theFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

    // Here, either iterate over the string array or use a List
    if (!nameList.Contains (theFileInfo.Name)) continue;

    var destination = soruceFolder + theFileInfo.Name;
        File.Move(file, destination);

}
```

Comment: you clearly did not get my question, I have to differentiate by name not type

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

```
 var pstFileFolder = "C:/Users/chnikos/Desktop/Test/";
        //var searchPattern = "HelloWorld.docx"+"Test.docx";
        string[] test = { "HelloWorld.docx", "Test.docx" };
        var soruceFolder = "C:/Users/chnikos/Desktop/CopyTest/";

        // Searches the directory for *.pst
        foreach (var file in test)
        {
            // Exposes file information like Name
            var theFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            var source = Path.Combine(soruceFolder, theFileInfo.Name);
            var destination = Path.Combine(pstFileFolder, file);
            if (File.Exists(source))
                File.Move(file, destination);

        }
```